# Spring boot web app with embedded tomcat giving 404 error outside of Netbeans

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, http-status-code-404, embedded-tomcat-8

I am creating a Spring Boot web app (deployed as a JAR file) which contains an embedded Tomcat server.  Everything works flawlessly on my dev machine but when i place the JAR file on a dedicated machine i get 404 errors no matter what i do.  Here is the relevant code :

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
<artifactId>LEM2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Lab Equipment Manager</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

     <!--JAVA-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--TOMCAT-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--SPRING-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!--MICROSOFT-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--HIBERNATE-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--LOMBOK-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSTL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>LabEquipmentManager</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

WebServerFactoryCustomizer bean :

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() 
{
    return factory -> factory.setContextPath("/LEM2");
}
```

ViewResolver bean :

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() 
{
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}
```

Part of the main controller (of course there is more to it, just including a part of it to show how the endpoints are built) :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private String main(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        if (request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedInUser") != null)
        {
            return "home";
        }
        else
        {
            return "login";
        }
    }
}
```

Again, everything works perfectly on my dev machine by doing localhost:8080/LEM2.  Any idea why it won't work when deployed on another server?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you checked your firewall ?

Comment: the issue also happens when browsing to localhost directly from that server

Comment: Also, i get the whitelabel error page which means it is definitely reaching Tomcat so this is more of a Spring / Servlet error.

Comment: Check if your firewall allows to use the port, or if it is not used by another app. Sometimes 8080 is used by other Apps and it cannot start

Comment: try to add to your properties the controller that starts the app <start-class>MainController</start-class>

Comment: On your dev machine, do you start the application using Java or directly with your IDE?

Comment: i start it using the "play" button in Netbeans

Comment: Interesting! What is "play"s configuration? Also try running the application on your local with a classic "java -jar xxx.jar" or at least the same way you run it on your problematic machine and show us what happens

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my dev machine when running it from the command line.  I placed the following cmd in the project's base folder :

java -jar target/LEM2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Everything works fine when accessing it in the browser with :

http://localhost:8080/LEM2

Comment: I am literally transporting the whole project folder to what should be its final resting place on the server and the issue manifests itself somehow.

Comment: Are you sure the application starts properly and is able to allocate the port 8080 (to verify if it's not taken by another application)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178364/discussion-between-gumol-and-martin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm that the server is not faulty by deploying on another one. If the other deployment works, look into your server and make sure that no proxy application or another web server is running at the same time.

Comment: Thank you brother / merci mon frère!

Answer (score 0):

try to know what netbeans is doing when you click on the play button and try that yourself on your server. should be like `java -jar <path-to-your-jar-containing-tomcat>`.
if you can't get this, and if it is an option, build a war and deploy the regular "tomcat" way.

Also, not sure what the contextPath might be, try checking that in the logs or using jmx console, it might show the contextPath.

Comment: the context path is LEM2 since i'm setting it explicitly in my WebServerFactoryCustomizer method posted above.

Comment: is this method called for sure? debug or breakpoint confirmed?

Comment: yes indeed, when running through Netbeans or through command line on my local machine the site works great and every page has /LEM2 in front of its name

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are deploying embedded jar in server that's why it's not working.

Comment: There is an actual tomcat server installed locally but it's not running.  I highly doubt both could clash.

Comment: Is there any exceptions on the log when you start the application or it logs application successfully started on 8080?